# Publish task to celery using redis as a message brocker

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have two backends in my app: Celery for background tasks and Tornado that maintains web services. I couldn't determine a way to push task to celery from tornado using redis pubsub channel. I don't know the name of the channel to push to and the transport protocol: json, msgpack. I couldn't find how to name a channel in celery documentation.

I have checked celery task protocol http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html. But that's not enough. At least reserved channel name must be determined somehow.

Comment: Why? What's the point of using Celery if you don't want to use its interface?

Comment: The question was "How can I be compat with celery interface without using additional REST or any other API" (without no new level of indirection). Anyway, I found the solution. ./manage.py celery inspect helps you to identify what is the routing mechanisms and protocol behind: routing_key = "", exchange="", content_type and so on. So I tried this and it works. I will post my answer at the end of the day by UTC +6.